# Parse error: syntax error, unexpected T_RETURN

Tags: php, sql

Getting this Problem. Tried my best, I looked up some stuff and they said that it could be the line above the error line (btw the error line is the "return mysql_insert_id();). Any help?

```
    function user_register($email, $name, $password) {
  $email = mysql_real_escape_string($email);
  $name = mysql_real_escape_string($name);
  mysql_query("INSERT INTO 'users' VALUES ('', '$email', '$name', '".md5 ($password)."')"
  return mysql_insert_id();
}
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Missing a closing paren:

```
function user_register($email, $name, $password) {
    $email = mysql_real_escape_string($email);
    $name = mysql_real_escape_string($name);
    mysql_query("INSERT INTO 'users' VALUES ('', '$email', '$name', '".md5 ($password)."')");
    return mysql_insert_id();
}
```

Comment: @user1043816 you should click the check mark to accept this answer.

Answer (score 4):

You forgot `);` after your query.