# Parse and syntax error, unexpected T_RETURN

Tags: php, wordpress, syntax

I got this problem. I was editing the Theme functions of my site when this occured:

**Parse error: syntax error, unexpected T_RETURN in /home/akoni77/public_html/katolikongpinoy.org/wp-content/themes/magazine-basic/functions.php on line 203**

When I looked up in the notepad, the line 203 will be on the highlighted (asterisked) line:

```
} else {
    $pbt_site = 800;
    $pbt_sidebar = 180;
    $pbt_sidewidget = 160;
    $pbt_content = 560;
}

// Set the content width based on the theme's design and stylesheet.
if ( = isset( $content_width ) )
    **$content_width = $pbt_content;**

function pbt_header_css() {
    global $pbt_site, $pbt_sidebar, $pbt_secondsidebar, $pbt_sidewidget, $pbt_sidewidget2, $pbt_content;
?>
<style type="text/css">
body { width: <?php echo $pbt_site; ?>px; }
```

How can this code be corrected?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Parse error: syntax error, unexpected T_RETURN](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8129978/parse-error-syntax-error-unexpected-t-return)

Answer (score 2):

You're missing something on the left side of the `=` here.  Or, more likely, the `=` doesn't belong there at all.

```
if ( = isset( $content_width ) )
//^^^^^^
// Probably should read
if (isset( $content_width ) )
```

As a general tip, the source of the actual error is very often in the statement that precedes the one identified by line number.  So in this case line 203 could not be parsed correctly because of an error immediately before it.

Comment: Not really - `isset` checks whether a variable has been assigned. So the `=` must be deleted.

Comment: @ThorstenDittmar but it does return a value which can be assigned. I already addressed the more likely case that it just should be there though.

Comment: Of course it does return a value that can be assigned! I have, however, always considered it the worst design flaw of C-like languages that an assignment should return a boolean value!! I just didn't want you to encourage anybody to check the success of an assignment in an `if` statement.

Comment: Actually, there has been no change at there at all from the original form. I had two wordpress sites using the same theme, this and the other one. I opened another site and compared the two on what is wrong. There is actually nothing different from the two. But I admit before this happened, I put codes in the box before them (the infected paragraph), but I erased them when I see what I expected did not happen. So I presume something was also deleted when I erased my applied code, but in comparison with the another blog, I saw nothing different between them. And the (=) sign is there originally

Comment: That can't be true, as the `if` line is incorrect syntax the way you've written it.

Comment: BTW, I put my applied code between "$pbt_content = 560; }" and "// Set the content width".. probably ,you may be right that something had happened before the line indicated... Thanks for more help guys.

Comment: Thank you for marking one of the ansers as "accepted solution" :-)

Comment: Guys, I'm sorry for a negligence,  I had double-checked my other blog's php... the equals (=_) sign is suppose to be an exclam. point (!)... so>>

if ( ! isset( $content_width ) )

Yet still nothing happens, must there be something to consider in this?

Comment: @user1093907 If you changed that to the `!` and still have a parse error, you'll need to show more code because the error is somewhere above what we see.

Answer (score 1):

Remove the `=` in the following line:

```
if ( = isset( $content_width ) )
    **$content_width = $pbt_content;**
```

**EDIT**
On a side note:

Michael suggested that you need to put something left of the `=` in your `if` statement, like

```
if ($someVar = isset($content_width))
```

However, this may be the source of errors: The condition here is *not*  the value of `isset`, but whether the assignment was successful or not. So this will jump into the `if` block whenever the assignment was successful.

Since you most probably want to jump into the `if` block if `$content_width` has been assigned a value, the statement in your case should read:

```
if (isset($content_width))
    ...
```

Comment: Thanks for downvoting. Mind providing a little information on why you downvoted? My reply is as valid as any other...

Comment: Thorsten, I'm sorry for a negligence, I had double-checked my other blog's php... the equals (=_) sign is suppose to be an exclam. point (!)... so>> if ( ! isset( $content_width ) ) Yet still nothing happens, must there be something to consider in this?